# Why do these RSpec examples fail?

Tags: ruby, rspec, rspec-rails

I am new to RSpec. These specs were generated by scaffolding.

I'm facing these message errors in my log:

```
Failures:

  1) ClientsController POST create with invalid params assigns a newly created but unsaved client as @client
     Failure/Error: expect(assigns(:client)).to be_a_new(Client)
       expected #<Client id: 1, name: "", phone: "", email: "", status: nil, created_at: "2016-05-14 14:56:01", updated_at: "2016-05-14 14:56:01"> to be a new Client(id: integer, name: string, phone: string, email: string, status: integer, created_at: datetime, updated_at: datetime)
     # ./spec/controllers/clients_controller_spec.rb:88:in `block (4 levels) in <top (required)>'

  2) ClientsController POST create with invalid params re-renders the 'new' template
     Failure/Error: expect(response).to render_template("new")
       expecting <"new"> but rendering with <[]>
     # ./spec/controllers/clients_controller_spec.rb:93:in `block (4 levels) in <top (required)>'

  3) ClientsController PUT update with invalid params re-renders the 'edit' template
     Failure/Error: expect(response).to render_template("edit")
       expecting <"edit"> but rendering with <[]>
     # ./spec/controllers/clients_controller_spec.rb:139:in `block (4 levels) in <top (required)>'

Finished in 0.28667 seconds (files took 5.4 seconds to load)
16 examples, 3 failures
```

My specs are below:

```
require 'rails_helper'

RSpec.describe ClientsController, :type => :controller do

  let(:valid_attributes) {
    {
      "name"   => "Mark Rodwell",
      "phone"  => '5585985463053',
      "email"  => 'markrodwell@gmail.com',
      "status" => 1
    }
  }

  let(:invalid_attributes) {
    {
      "name"   => "",
      "phone"  => '',
      "email"  => '',
      "status" => nil
    }
  }

  let(:valid_session) {
    {
      "user_type"             => 2,
      "status"                => 1,
      "name"                  => "Cristiano Carvalho",
      "email"                 => 'cristiano.codelab@gmail.com',
      "password"              => '12345678',
      "password_confirmation" => '12345678'
    }
  }

  describe "GET index" do
    it "assigns all clients as @clients" do
      client = Client.create! valid_attributes
      get :index, {}, valid_session
      expect(assigns(:clients)).to eq([client])
    end
  end

  describe "GET show" do
    it "assigns the requested client as @client" do
      client = Client.create! valid_attributes
      get :show, {:id => client.to_param}, valid_session
      expect(assigns(:client)).to eq(client)
    end
  end

  describe "GET new" do
    it "assigns a new client as @client" do
      get :new, {}, valid_session
      expect(assigns(:client)).to be_a_new(Client)
    end
  end

  describe "GET edit" do
    it "assigns the requested client as @client" do
      client = Client.create! valid_attributes
      get :edit, {:id => client.to_param}, valid_session
      expect(assigns(:client)).to eq(client)
    end
  end

  describe "POST create" do
    describe "with valid params" do
      it "creates a new Client" do
        expect {
          post :create, {:client => valid_attributes}, valid_session
        }.to change(Client, :count).by(1)
      end

      it "assigns a newly created client as @client" do
        post :create, {:client => valid_attributes}, valid_session
        expect(assigns(:client)).to be_a(Client)
        expect(assigns(:client)).to be_persisted
      end

      it "redirects to the created client" do
        post :create, {:client => valid_attributes}, valid_session
        expect(response).to redirect_to(Client.last)
      end
    end

    describe "with invalid params" do
      it "assigns a newly created but unsaved client as @client" do
        post :create, {:client => invalid_attributes}, valid_session
        expect(assigns(:client)).to be_a_new(Client)
      end

      it "re-renders the 'new' template" do
        post :create, {:client => invalid_attributes}, valid_session
        expect(response).to render_template("new")
      end
    end
  end

  describe "PUT update" do
    describe "with valid params" do
      let(:new_attributes) {
        {
          "name"   => "Mark James Rodwell",
          "phone"  => '5585985463053',
          "email"  => 'markrodwl@gmail.com',
          "status" => 1
        }
      }

      it "updates the requested client" do
        client = Client.create! valid_attributes
        put :update, {:id => client.to_param, :client => new_attributes}, valid_session
        client.reload
        expect(assigns(:client)).to eq(client)
      end

      it "assigns the requested client as @client" do
        client = Client.create! valid_attributes
        put :update, {:id => client.to_param, :client => valid_attributes}, valid_session
        expect(assigns(:client)).to eq(client)
      end

      it "redirects to the client" do
        client = Client.create! valid_attributes
        put :update, {:id => client.to_param, :client => valid_attributes}, valid_session
        expect(response).to redirect_to(client)
      end
    end

    describe "with invalid params" do
      it "assigns the client as @client" do
        client = Client.create! valid_attributes
        put :update, {:id => client.to_param, :client => invalid_attributes}, valid_session
        expect(assigns(:client)).to eq(client)
      end

      it "re-renders the 'edit' template" do
        client = Client.create! valid_attributes
        put :update, {:id => client.to_param, :client => invalid_attributes}, valid_session
        expect(response).to render_template("edit")
      end
    end
  end

  describe "DELETE destroy" do
    it "destroys the requested client" do
      client = Client.create! valid_attributes
      expect {
        delete :destroy, {:id => client.to_param}, valid_session
      }.to change(Client, :count).by(-1)
    end

    it "redirects to the clients list" do
      client = Client.create! valid_attributes
      delete :destroy, {:id => client.to_param}, valid_session
      expect(response).to redirect_to(clients_url)
    end
  end

end
```

Comment: It really helps if you post the smallest code sample that exhibits the problem. For example, there's no need to post the 13 specs that are passing when your question is about the 3 that are failing: 80% of the posted code is just noise a reader must scroll through

Comment: @Cristiano Carvalho what's your solusion?

Answer (score 0):

```
class Client < ActiveRecord::Base
  validates :name, presence: true
  validates :phone,:presence => true, :length => { :minimum => 9, :maximum => 13 }
end
```

thanks for the advice! now it works fine with no failures!